# error on button click in android

Tags: android, buttonclick

```
public boolean isValidPin(String pin) {

type = false; 
Cursor c =db .rawQuery( "select * from"+ pinTable+" where Pin='" + pin+ "'", null); 
if (c.getCount() > 0) 
{ 
c.moveToFirst(); 
type = true; 
}
 c.close(); 
return type; 
}
```

i have a button on a dialog box in android
wen iclick it stops forcefully...
this is the logcat error..

```
03-26 07:35:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(16907): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 07:35:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(16907): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-26 07:35:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(16907):    at com.android.lnt_form.WayDataBase.isValidPin(WayDataBase.java:147)
03-26 07:35:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(16907):    at com.android.lnt_form.LoginActivity$3.onClick(LoginActivity.java:133)
03-26 07:35:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(16907):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
03-26 07:35:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(16907):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
03-26 07:35:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(16907):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-26 07:35:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(16907):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-26 07:35:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(16907):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-26 07:35:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(16907):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-26 07:35:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(16907):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 07:35:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(16907):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-26 07:35:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(16907):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-26 07:35:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(16907):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-26 07:35:23.140: E/AndroidRuntime(16907):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

pls help .
how do i rectify it??

Comment: plz post your code, specially com.android.lnt_form.WayDataBase.isValidPin(WayDataBase.java:147)

Comment: plz also add LoginActivity class code

Comment: ` public boolean isValidPin(String pin) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   boolean type = false;

         Cursor c =db .rawQuery(
                 "select * from"+ pinTable+" where Pin='" + pin+ "'", null);
         if (c.getCount() > 0) {
             c.moveToFirst();
             type = true;
         }

         c.close();

         return type;

 }` this is the database

Comment: @user2210351 Add space between "from" and "tablename" and "where"

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/Jft38xYJ) here is the code for LoginActivity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not much to go on here, but I'm gonna take a stab at it and say that you didn't initialize your db before trying to access it. That would give a nullpointer on that row.